# Cannot add CheckBox to all rows

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to add a CheckBox in a listView for all items available in the listview, so I did this:

```
<ListView x:Name="Playing" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}" 
          SelectionChanged="Playing_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" >
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path = IsFavourite}"
                                  Checked="CheckBoxMatch_Checked" 
                                  Unchecked="CheckBoxMatch_UnChecked"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="{DynamicResource date}" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = MatchDate}"/>
```

the problem's that checkbox is displayed only for one item on the listview, why?

Comment: post more code. your xaml shows me a checkbox for every item.

Comment: post your .cs code as well

Comment: @Milan I applied this style: https://pastebin.com/qqdLWDF4 using `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path = IsFavourite}"
                                      Checked="CheckBoxMatch_Checked" 
                                      Unchecked="CheckBoxMatch_UnChecked"
                                      Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStar}"/>` if I remove the style the checkbox appear, why with the style not?

Comment: Don't post code through external URL, edit your original post instead. You're style is setting a `Content` property when the `CheckBox` is checked but not when it is not checked. Also, it's been a while since I've used a WPF ListView (I'm mostly working with third-party components), but check if your DataContext of the DataTemplate is your underlying ViewModel as with the third-party component I'm using it's not.

Comment: @RogerLeblanc he has a multidatatrigger for ischecked=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your

```
<Setter Property="Content">
     <Setter.Value>
          <Image Source="{StaticResource StarEmpty}"/>
      </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

with

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
     <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
              <Image Source="{StaticResource StarEmpty}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

and same with your other trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Content">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <Image Source="{StaticResource Star}"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{DynamicResource removeFromFavourite}"/>
                                </Trigger>
```

into

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
       <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
           <Setter.Value>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <Image Source="{StaticResource Star}"/>
                  <DataTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{DynamicResource removeFromFavourite}"/>
</Trigger>
```

does it work now?

Comment: great, press that upvote so that i get bragging points and have a nice day

Comment: I press it, but I can't send you upvote 'cause I've no enough rep, if you want add an upvote to mee too I'll be a nice night :)